# Does a third-party module need to implement hook_help()?

Tags: coding-standards

After having spent hours reading through (very old) coding standards and best practices threads on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org), and even trying to revive the [Contrib Development Best Practices](https://groups.drupal.org/contrib-development-best-practices) group on groups.drupal.org which seems to having been abandoned for years, I'm still struggling to getting an answer to whether a third-party module needs to implement [`hook_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21help%21help.api.php/function/hook_help/8.4.x) to comply with the [Module Documentation Guidelines](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/documenting-your-project/module-documentation-guidelines#hook_help) or not.

Above guidelines state

> **All but the most trivial modules should implement hook_help().**

Yet, **should** is not **must**, which sometimes leads to discussions within the [Security Advisory Application Issues Queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/projectapplications?order=last_comment_timestamp&sort=asc&status=8&text=&priorities=All&categories=All&component=All).

I was not able to identify someone to ask, whether it is a requirement or a (strong?) suggestion.

As we're currently reworking the [PAReview (pareview.sh)](https://pareview.sh) tool, it would be great to know for having a distinct severity for a missing hook_help(). That's why I'm hoping to getting a hint from the grey-bearded Drupalists here, on where to address this inquiry.

Don't get me wrong, I don't want to start a discussion here, nor subjective answers on whether there should be a hook_help or not. I just want to know which board is deciding such issues and where to ask when it comes to contrib module coding standards and best practices.

Comment: I rarely do unless its a contributed module. I've often found that the hook_help stuff generally isn't _too_ helpful - I think there is a core issue somewhere asking for that to instead read contents of a README.txt or .md file as the help docs, which almost all modules tend to have.

Comment: We usually do so only to providing links to external documentations, as regular users often don't see a README file. But that's not exactly the point of my question. :|

Answer (score 1):

Modules should implement `hook_help()` even for just giving a short description of the purpose of the module (an overview help page). The standard structure of that page is described in [Help text standards / Help page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/documenting-your-project/help-text-standards#s-4-help-page). `hook_help()` is the hook used from the core Help module.

In Drupal 8.8.x, a new experimental core module has been added: the Help Topics module. Its purpose is allowing modules to write their help pages as Twig template files with an embedded YAML header, for example like [ban.banning_ips.html.twig](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/core/modules/help_topics/help_topics/ban.banning_ips.html.twig).

```
---
label: 'Banning IP addresses'
related:
  - user.overview
---
{% set ban = render_var(url('ban.admin_page')) %}
<h2>{% trans %}Goal{% endtrans %}</h2>
<p>{% trans %}Ban visitors from one or more IP addresses from accessing and viewing your site.{% endtrans %}</p>
<h2>{% trans %}Steps{% endtrans %}</h2>
<ol>
  <li>{% trans %}In the <em>Manage</em> administrative menu, navigate to <em>Configuration</em> &gt; <em>People</em> &gt; <a href="{{ ban }}"><em>IP address bans</em></a>{% endtrans %}</li>
  <li>{% trans %}Enter an <em>IP address</em> and click <em>Add</em>.{% endtrans %}</li>
  <li>{% trans %}You should see the IP address you entered listed under <em>Banned IP addresses</em>. Repeat the above steps to ban additional IP addresses.{% endtrans %}</li>
</ol>
```

Since the module is experimental, third-party modules should not depend on that and use those files for their help text, especially because [the module is going to be merged with the Help module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3037230). The plan is also to [deprecate `hook_help()`](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3031642).

Third-party modules should:

- Drupal 7
  Implement `hook_help()` even to show a short overview page
- Drupal 8
  Implement `hook_help()` even to show a short overview page; consider writing integration with [the Tour module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/tour/overview) to add additional contextual help to any page in the shape of a tour, which can have multiple steps, each one describing part of a page (such as different form elements in an administrative form)
- Drupal 9 (or 10, depending from when the *Help Topics* module will be merged into the *Help* module)
  Write topics pages even to show a short overview page; consider writing integration with the *Tour* module to add additional contextual help

Answer (score 0):

I never found anything about it, but I think that is highly recommended implement this hook.

The reason, I remember when I started with Drupal that many modules did not have a README.txt file and did not have the help page, even in the module page you did not find any information about how to use the module.

So, this is not required for a module, but I think that you should show a suggestion to implement the hook with some information about how to use the module.